# Mapping of shapes in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following sample code:

```r
df <- data.frame(name = c("a", "b", "c"),
                 date = as.Date(c("2020-01-01", "2020-01-03", "2020-01-05")),
                 pch = c(18, 19, 1))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = pch))
```

I would like to use the shapes 18, 19 and 1 (just as specified in the column `pch` of my data). Unfortunately, when I have numeric values in the column `pch` I get the message "A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape", but when I convert them into a factor I dont get the shapes I want because ggplot assigns the shapes automatically to my factor levels. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try this:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = factor(pch)))+
  scale_shape_manual(values=df$pch)+
  labs(shape='pch')
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape=pch))+
  scale_shape_identity()
```

Output:

[image]

It is also possible to avoid all wordy code with next solution using the `I()` function (Many thanks and credit to **@teunbrand**):

```
#Code 3
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = date, y = name)) + 
  geom_point(aes(shape = I(pch)))
```

Same output.

Comment: I just want to add that the `scale_shape_identity()` isn't necessary if you use `aes(shape = I(pch))` to take the values in the `pch` columns as-is.

Comment: @teunbrand Golden suggestion, I will update with credit to you! Many thanks!

Comment: @teunbrand Done, many thanks! But in that case how can I add a legend?

Comment: For the legend you would need to add the identity scale. I just tried `+ guides(shape = "legend")`, but that doesn't work.